# Get count of duplicate rows in DISTINCT ON

Tags: sql, postgresql

In any `SELECT` query, where a `DISTINCT ON` is used, how can one additionally get the number of duplicates for each row in the result set?

Take e.g.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (building)
  building,
  name
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

This will only return the first result for each building. I want to add another column, so the results look like this:

```
name | building | excluded
Fred | Office   | 0
Bob  | Storage  | 3
```

when there are more people than Bob in Storage. I'm using Postgres 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
with data (name, building) as (
  values 
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Fred', 'Office'),
    ('Tim', 'Home'),
    ('Tim', 'Home')
)
select distinct on (building) *, 
       count(*) over (partition by building) - 1 as excluded
from data
order by building;
```

returns:

```
name | building | excluded
-----+----------+---------
Tim  | Home     |        1
Fred | Office   |        0
Bob  | Storage  |        3
```

This works because the window function is evaluated before the `distinct on ()`

However this means doing some work twice. I think it might be faster to re-use the partitioning "work" to also filter out the duplicates:

```
with ranked as (
  select *, 
         count(*) over w - 1 as excluded, 
         row_number() over w as rn
  from your_table
  window w as (partition by building)
) 
select *
from ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Your last approach even answers a follow up question I was about to ask wrt conditional deduplication. Neat.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `group by` instead of `distinct on` (to avoid window functions):

```
with data (name, building) as (
  values 
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Bob', 'Storage'),
    ('Fred', 'Office'),
    ('Tim', 'Home'),
    ('Tim', 'Home')
)   
select min(name), building, count(*)- 1 as excluded
from data
group by building
order by building;

 min  | building | excluded 
------+----------+----------
 Tim  | Home     |        1
 Fred | Office   |        0
 Bob  | Storage  |        3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Is there any significant difference in e.g. performance on large tables using GROUP instead of DISTINCT?

Comment: The `group by` approach only works as long as no additional columns need to be select - but in that case I think it's indeed  more efficient

Comment: Yes, the difference should be significant in favor of `group by`. You have to use aggregates for other columns (like `min(name)` in the example).

Answer (score -1):

Use window functions?

```
select
first_value(name) over (partition by building order by /* your order */) first_name
first_value(building) over (partition by building order by  /* your order */) building,
count(*) over (partition by building order by /* your order */) - 1 as excluded
from (
    select name, building
    from my_source_table
);
```